# What is _valgrind in Zsh?

Tags: macos, zsh

I'm using macOS 11.0.1 and wanted to install `valgrind` for C programming. To check whether it came installed on macOS on default, I typed `valgr` in the terminal and pressed tab, and to my surprise, this phrase was autocompleted to `_valgrind`. `valgrind` itself, however, is not installed.

Doing a little digging (`type _valgrind`), I found `_valgrind` is a function defined in `/usr/share/zsh/5.8/functions/_valgrind`.

So my question is: what is this function, and what does it do? My scripting skills are not great so I'm not really able to make heads or tails of this function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions prefixed with underscore (especially if they're from `/usr/share/zsh`) are often **tab-completion scripts** – they get invoked when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> while writing a command line, and they produce the list of suggestions that shows up. (No, the suggestions aren't taken directly from the command itself; the list has to be hand-maintained.)

For example, if you enter `valgrind --maxTab`, zsh calls the _valgrind function to generate suggestions such as `--max-threads=`.

(Note that the underscore naming is just a general convention – but it's not what actually *makes* it a completion function; it still has to be bound to some word using 'compdef'.)

(And another note, the zsh 5.8 that's available for Arch Linux seems to use a very [different structure](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html) for the completion scripts – they are no longer functions, but files with a special `#compdef` header. I don't know how that works, and I don't know why the same zsh version does it differently on the two systems.)